# Loss function with argmax returns int

Tags: tensorflow

I'm defining a loss function RMSE as follows:

```
model.pred= tf.argmax(model.props, 1)
model.actual = tf.argmax(model.y, 1)
model.RMSE = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(model.predictedSteer, model.actualSteer))))
```

model.pred is int64 but sqrt gives a compilation error because it requires float input. When I use tf.cast the loss function becomes not differentiable. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `argmax` is non-differentiable, so most functions involving it will also be non-differentiable. Without knowing more about the problem it's difficult to give a solution. If it's a classification problem use the logits (`pred`) rather than the argmax.